# Is there a way to open a copy of a document(Word, PDF, ect.)in Windows, so that the master copy is always preserved?

Tags: windows, pdf, ms-word

I have some forms in various formats(Word and/or PDF) that have prefilled information pertaining to the function they are intended for--such as addresses and control numbers. Typically a user would create a copy of the document and then edit that copy, preserving the master copy. However, this is not always the case and mistakes are being introduced into the master.

Assuming all users are accessing these files in file explorer via a network share, and all utilizing Windows 10, is there a way to ensure that when a user clicks the file to open it they are actually opening a copy of that document?

Comment: Could you make the master files read-only on the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try restricting the edit permissions of the file, which would force users to copy the file before hand.

Comment: read-only attribute is a possible alternative to that

Comment: That makes sense, I think I was overthinking the problem. I was imagining a way that simply opening the file would create the copy for them. But restricting the permissions would just ask them to save it as a copy. Thanks!

Comment: In Word, if you use a Template, double-clicking on it will create a new document based on the template. Here is my webpage on templates: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm